# Is it possible to run a .Net UWP Class Library on Azure?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, uwp

I thought up an idea for a website that would involve some video editing happening on the web server.   Microsoft UWP [has a library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-compositions-and-editing) that does the video editing functions I'm looking to perform...  Amazing!!

My problem is I don't know if it's possible to get my website to run UWP code on Azure. Web Jobs seem like what I'd prefer to use to kick off this code, but web jobs don't appear to be able to run UWP code and without UWP code I don't see a library that can perform the video editing I'd like to do.  Does anybody know if it's possible to run UWP code on Azure?   If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think WebJobs are especially suited for this scenario. They are part of the WebApp platform as a service offering that abstracts the underlying operating system for you to be able to focus on building the code itself and deploy as easily as possible.

UWP on the other hand is a **Windows-specific** app platform which has many requirements including running on **Windows 10**. Because you don't know which concrete operating system the web app will run on, it is not easy to say if the APIs would work.

That said, you could theoretically use UWP APIs in a web app as well, because there is a [`UwpDesktop` NuGet package](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/) that allows it mainly targeted for desktop apps. It is a long shot but you can certainly try it.

As a preferable solution, I would still look to find another library that suits your needs, as the choice on NuGet is pretty broad and one of those should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I decided not using this library for video editing and instead looking into using ffmpeg to do what it is I want.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio)

These have about the same working as webjobs, however expand beyond the limitations of webjobs. These are also more versatile in what they can do and how they can be created.

[webjobs vs functions](https://stackify.com/azure-webjobs-vs-azure-functions/)